# Finding uncertainty in coefficients from polyfit in Matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have a data set of x- and y-values, that I want make a linear fit on. Using `polyfit(x,y,1)` I get the coefficients `a` and `b` for a linear fit `y=ax+b` for this data, but I would also like to find the uncertainty or standard deviation for these coefficients. Does anyone know an easy way of doing this?

My Google-fu only gave me [this](http://www.mathworks.se/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/103667) result, and seeing as the last answer in that thread is a correction to first answer, I don't know if I should trust any of the answers. The answer from that thread is:

```
[z,s]=polyfit(x,y,1);
ste = sqrt(diag(inv(s.R)*inv(s.R')).*s.normr.^2./s.df);
```

Comment: I am not seeing how to retrieve something like a_uncert or b_uncert from freude's answer. Can anyone clarify that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything can be done with `polyfit` function only. Read about its optional output parameters in
http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html

For instance:

```
[p,S,mu] = polyfit(x,y,n)
```

where mu is the two-element vector [μ1,μ2], where μ1=mean(x), μ2=std(x)

To compute error, you have to use another function taking output of `polyfit`:

`[y,delta] = polyval(p,x,S,mu)`

This function computes polynomial function from coefficients and estimates the error.

Comment: This is probably the latest reply ever, but thanks for the answer! Marked it as correct now.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the curve fitting toolbox installed, you can use [fit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html) to determine the uncertainty of the slope `a` and the y-intersect `b` of a linear fit. 
Note: `x` and `y` have to be column vectors for this example to work.

```
cf = fit(x,y,'poly1');
```

The option `'poly1'` tells the fit function to perform a linear fit. The output is a "fit object". You can access the fit results with the methods `coeffvalues`and `confint`.  Assuming that the confidence intervals are symmetrically spaced around the fitted values (which in my experience is true in all reasonable cases), you can use the following code:

```
cf_coeff = coeffvalues(cf);
cf_confint = confint(cf);
a = cf_coeff(1);
b = cf_coeff(2);
a_uncert = (cf_confint(2,1) - cf_confint(1,1))/2;
b_uncert = (cf_confint(2,2) - cf_confint(1,2))/2;
```

One note of caution: The errors of `a` and `b` will generally be correlated, which makes them unnecessarily big. You can reduce this correlation by subtracting the mean x-value of your data before fitting. My Statistics skills aren't good enough to provide a solid explanation on the reasons for that - hopefully one of the more seasoned statistics experts can edit my answer (or provide their own and delete mine) to give details on this side-note.